# Append my application logs to tomcat's ones

Tags: tomcat, servlets

Tomcat already has a log displaying information messages like startup ones.
I'd like for a servlet of mine to append some custom info to this log.

How to get a tomcat's logger instance from a servlet, so to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.out` and `System.err` messsages by default written to `catalina.out` log file, BUT most production systems disable `System.out` logging to a file.

So the best method to log tomcat's own log files from a servlet is to use **`javax.servlet.ServletContext.log(...)`** method. Log messages with this method are handled by internal Tomcat logging.

For more information check the [Tomcat Servlet Logging API](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

when you write to `stdo` in ypur servlet, the output redirected to tomcat's log file `./logs/catalina.out`. so just use this:

```
System.out.println("Hello");
```